# Device discovery and Distance measurement

Tags: wireless-networking, arduino

The goal of my project is to discover devices with Wi-Fi or Bluetooth turned on (not connedcted anywhere) and measure the distance between those devices and my search devices. The search devices will be some Arduino-like devices which would have Wifi/BT turned on. I'd like to now if it is possible to measure the distance from my search device to the unconnected device. I googled this issue and I found that I can use either RSSI or Triangulation but I don't know whether these solutions apply to my problem. Furthermore I'd like to know if it is possible to discover neareby devices that have GSM turned on and measure the distance to my search devices just as I'd like with Wifi and BT.

Comment: You can measure the distance by measuring the signal, but it's not accurate, you know noise, walls and other devices. the same thing with GSM, I think it's better to ask at Arduino section to have a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is known in the Amateur Radio world as a "[foxhunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmitter_hunting)".

The basic concept of a foxhunt is that you use highly directional antennnas and sensitive signal-strength meters to triangulate the general area of the transmitter, and then repeat the process (possibly using attenuators) until you find the source.

Generally, wifi cards designed for client devices have a pretty poor signal meter that is based on RSSI rather than actual power, making them ill suited to this purpose (not that you couldn't do it, you'll just have issues getting to the "last mile" of actually finding the device). You'd do far better with a purpose built signal meter and antenna for the bands you're interested in - Bluetooth and WiFi both being 2.4GHz, and GSM being anywhere from 400MHz to 1.9GHz depending on where you are in the world and who's network you're looking for.

A couple challenging caveats: the signals you're describing are all designed to only transmit periodically and use spread-spectrum techniques meaning they're not always on the exact same frequency. You're also going to have a fun time separating the relatively strong signals from nearby WiFi routers or GSM towers from the weaker signals of the devices (at least until you get in closer).

Comment: Thanks for the info. For "purpose built antenna" do you mean specific antennas or the regular usb antennas would do the job. And do you think it is possible to dicover the GSM devices not the GSM towers.

Comment: I mean a real antenna connected to a signal meter. "USB antenna" makes me think you're talking about WiFi cards again.
Anything is possible, I'm just warning you that it might take more skill to pull out devices among the stronger signals.